# Mongo db import single json file having several documents

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoimport

Am new to mongo db. I have a single json file which contains several documents.

When i try to upload the file through mongoimport, the file is considered as a single document to be created where as there are several documents to be created through the same file.

Below is import command.

```
mongoimport --db mydb --collection testData --type json --file var/www/html/orders.json --jsonArray
```

Running this command throws the following error:

```
exception:JSONArray file too large
```

Comment: Read the mongoimport man page. "Limited to imports of 16 MB or smaller"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From MongoDB docs, always refer to docs before posting on stackoverflow:

> --jsonArray
>   Changed in version 2.2: The limit on document size increased from 4MB to 16MB.
>
> Accept import of data expressed with multiple MongoDB documents within a single JSON array.
>
> Use in conjunction with mongoexport --jsonArray to import data written as a single JSON array. Limited to imports of 16 MB or smaller.

Comment: I know about the 16 MB limitation. But the limitation is for a single document. I have 54000 documents which are all of size less than 16MB.
The issue am facing is that i need to upload all the documents together which are in a single json file.
I have read on stackoverflow that we can upload multiple documents through a single json file. I tried uploading the file , I just need to know the proper way. of which am unaware.

Comment: This should work  mongoimport -d mydb -c testData < var/www/html/orders.json

Comment: Be aware jsonArray doesn't mean file should be a json array. Documents should not have embracing array brackets and don't separate them with commas otherwise you get misleading error about the file is too large.

Comment: Though mongoimport is limited. It can't handle files with more 10000 records. So I have to used sed '20000,30000!d'  | mongoimport

Comment: @vmr sifting through the esoteric tomes of MongoDB documentation would take much, much longer than just asking someone who might know immediately on StackOverflow.

Comment: @DaneelS.Yaitskov that isn't true. I've used MongoDB to import a single json file containing 25,000 documents in an array. Maybe a new version has improved it?

Answer (score 0):

Mongoimport is used to upload the JSON file into Mongodb. File should be in well formatted manner.
MongoDB will limit to 16MB file.

```
mongoimport --host hosturl --port 27017 --username uname --password pwd --   collection collname --db marketing --file filepathwithFilename
```

[Example Refference](https://web.archive.org/web/20160214180502/http://www.inmongodb.net:80/2015/08/upload-json-file-to-mongodb.html)